# Node JS app shuts down after ten seconds in Production env but runs fine on local env

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a Node JS app which serves as a backend for a React web app. The application when started serves the React app and handles all the API calls. I connect to a MySQL database for data fetch. The app runs normally on local environment but crashes when deployed on an Ubuntu server(on AWS). On server, the app starts normally but after few seconds it crashes.
This is the error it throws when started

```
Error connecting: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/ubuntu/localSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:412:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:422:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/localSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ubuntu/localSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/ubuntu/localSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/home/ubuntu/localSystem/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/localSystem/model/db.js:29:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

DB connection file (db.js):

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host     : 'xxxx',
    port : xxxx,
    user     : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'myDB'
});
connection.getConnection(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting: ' + err.stack)
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId)
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app = express();
var appRoutes = require('./routes/appRoutes');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', appRoutes);


module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var app = require('./server');
//const { connection } = require('./database');

var port = 5001;

app.set('port', port);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`server on port ${app.get('port')}`);
});
```

AppModel.js

```
var sql = require('./db.js');

//Task object constructor
var Task = function(task){
    this.task = task.task;
    this.status = task.status;
    this.created_at = new Date();
};

Task.getAllCustomerStatusRecords = function getAllCustomerStatusRecords(result) {
    sql.query("Select a, b, c, call_provider_id from myTable order by id desc limit 20", function (err, res) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("error: ", err);
                result(null, err);
            }
            else {
              console.log('Customer status records : ', res);  
              result(null, res);
            }
        });
      sql.releaseConnection() 
};
```

I have a similar set up for another Node app but without mysql and it runs without issues.I'm not sure why it crashes in this case.

EDIT: 
The API request does make a DB call. However that is only when the user explicitly selects some options and then makes a fetch call on the webpage. Initially though, there are no outwards API calls either to Db or external services.

Comment: Is your nodeJS server able to connect to the mysql database in your production environment? It looks as it isn't.

Comment: Even if mysql connection fails..im unable to understand why the whole app crashes. Even the react app is not served.

Comment: Because its an error that isnt handled. So it will crash,